# Render multiple HTML elements inline using CSS

Tags: html, css, web

On a demo webpage I'm trying to whip up, I have the following elements in a div:

```
 <div class="output">
      <code class="input-output">hello:</code>
      <samp clsss="proc-output">world</samp>
    </div>
```

How do I make both elements render on the same line like so:

> `hello: world`

Comment: add "display: inline;" or  "display: inline-block;" to code and samp tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:inline-block` or `display:inline` will do what you need.

```css
.input-output, .proc-output {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="output">
  <code class="input-output">hello:</code>
  <samp clsss="proc-output">world</samp>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define these elements as inline (in css file):

```
code.input-output, samp.proc-output {
    display: inline;
}
```

Or You could use spans:

```
<div class="output">
    <span class="input-output">hello:</span>
    <span clsss="proc-output">world</span>
</div>
```

You should use inline elements. It's main diference between span and div.